# I want pan and zoom functionality (like a MapView) on my own map image

Tags: android, zooming

How can I get my own image to be able to pan and zoom (like a MapView)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried hosting an image in a WebView (built-in pan and zoom), but there were a number of problems.  I ended up extending the View class and overriding onDraw.  It was not hard, once I finally decided to use that method.

Comment: do you support pinch zoom? would you be interested in posting source (I'm looking at same problem - would like to avoid reinventing the wheel)

Comment: It didn't support pinch zoom.  Back then was before Android had multitouch.  I don't think I have the source anymore.  The project was abandoned.