# Full size image in ImageView

Tags: android, scaling, imageview

I'm trying to draw an image in an ImageView, but i want it to be unscaled, with scrollbars as necessary. How can I accomplish this? Right now I just have a drawable set as the android:src of the ImageView in the XML. This autoscales the image to fit the screen width.

I read that this might be because of the compatibility mode (developing for 1.5, testing on 2.1), but then I added

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />
```

to my manifest, and nothing changed.

Any clues?

--

Edit: I used `android:scaleType="center"` on the ImageView, and this displays the full image (can't believe I didn't see this before), but I still only get a vertical scrollbar. Using `android:scrollbars="horizontal"` on the ScrollView that's wrapped around the ImageView (obviously) hides the vertical scrollbar, but doesn't show a horizontal scrollbar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this [example](http://www.anddev.org/large_image_scrolling_using_low_level_touch_events-t11182.html) it helps

Comment: Perfect! Well, perfectly adaptable to my needs! :)

Comment: The link provided is invalid!!

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me (using an HorizontalScrollView inside a ScrollView):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">


    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    >
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagen"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="center"
            />        
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to size the ImageView to the size of the Bitmap and place the ImageView into a ScrollView.  But you may run into memory issues trying to display a large image.