# android multitouch image zooming?

Tags: android, imageview, multi-touch

I'm displaying an image on full screen now i want to zoom it in or out.
Any one guide on how I can implement multi touch image zooming?

I am using the 2.1 sdk version.

Comment: need to provide the version of android you're targeting

Comment: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Answer (score 9):

There is the possibility to use a [webview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to display a local file. The Webview has integrated multitouch zooming. Have a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) regarding this topic.

Comment: means zoomcontrols not the webview.

Comment: sorry I can't understand your comments. If you want multitouch zooming and zoom controls for an Image you can show the image in an webview this will add multitouch zooming for the image and also show the zoom controls after the first touch event on the view

Comment: A web view is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

I have a working implementation for 2.1+

WebView solution caused problems for me on 4.0.x (lot's of weird white spaces appearing)

https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

Might be useful for someone...

Answer (score 5):

A [recent post on the Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) includes an [example](http://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/source/checkout) that does exactly what you ask.  Unfortunately, it relies upon [ScaleGestureDetecter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html) which makes its first appearance in Froyo.

Comment: b ut it is for 2.2 sdk version

Comment: is there any way to implement it through 2.1?

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using the intent "android.intent.action.VIEW" and letting the phone's built in image viewer display your image? It will probably use multi-touch controls if the phone supports it.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW

Answer (score 1):

Regarding gesture-imageview lib:
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview

it's in fact useful, but unfortunatelly it has some bugs, like:
https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/issues/37

Anyway, good lib to try. It solved my usecase.