# How to enable Zoom and Pan functions in Android Gallery widget?

Tags: android, gallery, imageview

The ImageView in the Android Gallery widget does not provide  Zoom and Pan functions.

Does anyone know how to enable those functions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "zoom and pan" for ImageView or for Gallery. You either need to find third-party code that provides this, or write it yourself.

Here are some links for implementing your own zoom logic on an ImageView:

http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/category/tutorials/zoom/

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

[android multitouch image zooming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055133/android-multitouch-image-zooming/3059280#3059280)

Here are existing multi-touch-enabled widgets:

http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/