# Zoom in Zoom Out image

Tags: android, zooming

I have to display an image which need to zoom in by stretching with two fingers.
And zoom out with the same process.

```
/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, WrapMotionEvent event) {
float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

Its not working.
Any good link or tutorial to study about it???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055133/android-multitouch-image-zooming

Comment: What i have tried for zooming,it zoom the image. but not work while i tried to zoom it in by stretching with two fingers

Comment: @SidratulMuntaha Have you solved this???