# how to implement pinch zooming on a  programmatically created Imageview in android?

Tags: android, imageview, pinchzoom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android multitouch image zooming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3055133/android-multitouch-image-zooming)

how to implement pinch zooming on a Imageview, programmatically created in android ?

Comment: [Try to see here](http://www.google.com/search?q=android+imageview+pinch+zoom&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/

and [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

also see : http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.se/2012/04/pinching-zoom-in-android-image-view-or.html

and :  http://www.mysecretroom.com/www/programming-and-software/android-multi-touch-handling

Comment: This library will do it for you plus a few other useful things.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578320/how-to-apply-zoom-drag-and-rotation-to-an-image-in-android/47861501#47861501