# I want to zoom in and zoom out my image when i contract or expand my image with fingers

Tags: android

This is My Fragment code i just want to Zoom in and Zoom out my image with my fingers . i don't want to Use zoom Controls .

```
package com.example.shivnandan.listview;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ZoomControls;

public class Alert_Fragment1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
{

ImageView vieww;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {



        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_frag1, null);
      vieww = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView16);

        return v;
    }

}
```

This is my layout in which i have an image in the image view and i am using a relative layout.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:id="@+id/imageView16"
        android:background="@drawable/alert_actttttttttt"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use external lib https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to implement pinch zooming on a  programmatically created Imageview in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049264/how-to-implement-pinch-zooming-on-a-programmatically-created-imageview-in-andro)

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add TouchImageView.class in your project



import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            // Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}

then in .xml write below code to load image

 <com.example.test.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

in your activity create ref and you can load image to imageView  -

TouchImageView imageView = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
```

Comment: Its showing this exception.android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.test.TouchImageView

Comment: i use package name com.example.test , so just change it. Open your TouchImageView class copy package name and replace it in your .xml layout

Comment: i dont see a package name in my TouchImageView Class... Help

Comment: package name is the first line in your TouchImageView.class, Can you just copy everything from your TouchImageView.class n paste in comment, will tell your package name

Comment: Then change below code in your xml- 

 <com.example.shivnandan.listview.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

Answer (score 0):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/thumb_button_1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/thumb1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_image_1" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:contentDescription="@string/description_zoom_touch_close" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Define a animation for zoom in and zoom out

```
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
// If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
// immediately and proceed with this one.
if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
}

// Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(
        R.id.expanded_image);
expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

// Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
// This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
final Point globalOffset = new Point();

// The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
// and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
// view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
// bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
// properties (X, Y).
thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
findViewById(R.id.container)
        .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

// Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
// bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
// stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
// factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
float startScale;
if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
        > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
    // Extend start bounds horizontally
    startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
    float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
    float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
    startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
    startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
} else {
    // Extend start bounds vertically
    startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
    float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
    float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
    startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
    startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
}

// Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
// begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
// thumbnail.
thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

// Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
// to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
// is the center of the view).
expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

// Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
// scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set
        .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
        startScale, 1f)).with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        mCurrentAnimator = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
        mCurrentAnimator = null;
    }
});
set.start();
mCurrentAnimator = set;

// Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
// to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
// the expanded image.
final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
        // back to their original values.
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(ObjectAnimator
                    .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.Y,startBounds.top))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, 
                                    View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;
    }
});
}
```

Then inside your activity do this

```
public class ZoomActivity extends FragmentActivity {
// Hold a reference to the current animator,
// so that it can be canceled mid-way.
private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

// The system "short" animation time duration, in milliseconds. This
// duration is ideal for subtle animations or animations that occur
// very frequently.
private int mShortAnimationDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zoom);

    // Hook up clicks on the thumbnail views.

    final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
        }
    });

    // Retrieve and cache the system's default "short" animation time.
    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
            android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
}
...
}
```

For more information about it visit [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)