# how to zoom image

Tags: java, android, zooming

hai my images are gallery all image display in same view but i expect the selected image only zoom for my gallery that type how to create any one help how to create give me your idea.....now i am post my screenshot.....help me....

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bala,
 [Refer this url,](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2010/05/18/android-one-finger-zoom-tutorial-part-1/) for zomming an image

Comment: ok but i expect simple zoom when i move the cursor into the image just zoom and difference between other images....

Comment: and one more that image are retrieve from videos if i click that videos its play....its not only image....if i make any mistake tell me...thats way i am asking u just difference between selected image and other images...i expect little bit zoom...if i double click that image will be play so when i touch the image just zoom...if any idea tell me...

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can find what you need here:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Or take a look at this post:
[how can i get zoom functionality for images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Comment: and one more thing that image are retrieve from videos if i click that videos its play....its not only image....if i make any mistake tell me...thats way i am asking u just difference between selected image and other images...i expect little bit zoom...if i double click that image will be play so when i touch the image just zoom...if any idea tell me...