# How to get zoom value of arbitrary matrix?

Tags: android, matrix, rotation, zooming, scale

An image is scaled by a matrix:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postScale(...);
matrix.postTranslate(...);
matrix.postRotate(...);
...
```

I hope the zoomed image won't be less than the half of original, so the total zoom should not less that 0.5.

But how to do that? I tried to get the first value of matrix to check:

```
float pendingZoom = 0.6f;

float[] values = new float[9];
Matrix.getValues(values);
float scalex = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
```

Then:

```
if(scalex<0.5) {
    pendingZoom = pendingZoom * (0.5f / scalex);
}
```

unfortunately, it doesn't work sometimes. If the image has been rotated, the `scalex` may be negative, the `pendingZoom` will be negative too.

How to do this correctly?

---

**UPDATE**

I just found the `values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]` is not a realiable zoom value. I use it to calculate the new width of a rect, it's not correct.

Instead, I tried to map two points by the matrix, and calculate the two distances:

```
PointF newP1 = mapPoint(matrix, new PointF(0, 0));
PointF newP2 = mapPoint(matrix, new PointF(width, 0));
float scale = calcDistance(newP1, newP2) / width;
```

I can get correct `scale` value now. But I'm not sure if it's best solution.

Comment: Does anyone know why matrix after rotation is different? It seems that after postRotate "scale x" is not under Matrix.MSCALE_X index (which is 0), but under 1 index.

Comment: Decomposing a matrix into translation, scaling, and rotation is explained [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13150/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
    float scalex = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float skewy = values[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];
    float scale = (float) Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy);
```

This solution looks simpler but I think that your's is much more clear and almost as fast as this one.

Comment: @Freewind I think you solution is just great. It is clear how it works and any solution of this problem requires square root extraction so it can't be done much faster. Only advice I have is don't do new PointF() in code responsible for scrolling since it will trigger garbage collector and it's bad for scrolling performance. Use some pre-created PointF member variable instead.

Comment: Updated my answer just to offer another kind of solution

Comment: @nickes This answer saved my day! But could you explain a little bit more about this? I mean, why Math.sqrt(scalex * scalex + skewy * skewy) is the answer rather than values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] or values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y]?

Comment: I need an explanation for that formula

Answer (score 0):

you can just take the absolute value

```
Math.abs(mMatrixValues[Matrix.MSCALE_X]);
```