# image view zoom with finger spread in android like gallery images

Tags: android

I want to zoom images like gallery images, where we can zoom in and zoom out the images by finger spread and shrink. How to do it? Can any body help?

Thanks & Reagrds

Answer (score 2):

What you're essentially asking for is multi-touch zoom for an image, right? If so, this should be the answer you're looking for:

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Answer (score 0):

I made a ZoomableImageView for this thing as I could not get anything decent. Source is here:
https://github.com/a85/WebComicViewer/blob/master/src/com/rickreation/ui/ZoomableImageView.java

It supports pinch and zoom, double tap zoom in and out and sets proper limits. You might have to tweak it a bit though. Let me know if you have any problems.