# Zooming a ImageView in a ViewGroup

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, viewgroup

I have different ImageView in a ViewGroup. Every ImageView has onTouch event like this:

```
      public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event){
      ImageView view = (ImageView)v;

      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK )
      {
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

              savedMatrix.set(matrix);
              start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
              Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
              mode = DRAG;

              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
              mode = NONE;
              Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
              oldDist = spacing(event);
              Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
              if (oldDist > 10f)
              {
                  savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                  midPoint(mid, event);
                  mode = ZOOM;
                  Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
              }
              break;
          case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
              if (mode == DRAG)
              {
                  matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                  matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
              }
              else if (mode == ZOOM)
              {
                  float newDist = spacing(event);
                  Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
                  if (newDist > 10f)
                  {
                      matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                      float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                      matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                  }
              }
              break;
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "setting matrix " + matrix);
      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);

      return true; // Indicate event was handled
  }
```

In logcat I see that onTouch event was handled but nothing happen. 
In ViewGroup I use InterceptTouchEvent for drag ImageView and move sliding view like android homescreen.

I think that there's a problem between ViewGroup and ImageView on dispacth touch event for zoom or there's a particular setting for ViewGroup. Can someone tell me if is possible zoom inside a child of a ViewGroup and how implement it?

Comment: I use this post to find a good solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752998/image-view-zoom-with-finger-spread-in-android-like-gallery-images But now I have OOM problem with large bitmap.. anyone can help me?