# Problem with zoom in functionality with scrollView in android?

Tags: android, scrollbar

I am new to android I am developing a small application in which i used few images i had implement on touch functionality in it with view flipper that user can flip the images with finger touch than i made two button for zoom in and zoom out and  add Scroll view in it.But the problem is that when i add scroll view my on touch functionality can't work and when i remove the scroll view i can able to flip the images with on touch. So can you give any suggestion so that my On touch functionality can work with scroll view.

Thanks in advance!

Aman

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910)

I hope it helps.