# Error inflating class TouchImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I'm trying to spruce up my image viewer activity by converting from an ImageView to a TouchImageView, per the answer here: [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

However, I get an error when my activity is attempting to load:

> Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class TouchImageView

Here's my **image_viewer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <!-- 
    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    -->

    <TouchImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />  

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my code inside onCreate of **ImageViewer.java** (though I'm pretty sure that execution never even gets this far):

```
    if(filepath != null && filepath.length() > 0 && new  File(filepath).exists())
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);

        TouchImageView imgView = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
        imgView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
```

Any ideas as to why or what is causing this error?  What I saw was the inner most exception/cause.  Not sure how I can get more details about the error.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**:

Exception gets thrown on execution of this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.image_viewer);
```

Further detail on the error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.TouchImageView in
>   loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfde70

Comment: is that your entire XML file?  it says line 15, but there are less lines than that there.  Also - try going in to debug mode in eclipse, if you can, and sticking a breakpoint at the start of your onCreate and then step through and see how far you get.

Comment: I removed commented out code.  I'll put it back in for accuratcy.  :)

Comment: And added updated error info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to have the fully qualified name to any custom view classes. e.g:

```
<com.kon.thing.TouchImageView ... />
```

The JVM can't find your class.

Answer (score 0):

make sure u have entered a correct package name in xml
like..

```
<com.gallery.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```