# Android URL Image

Tags: image, url, android-widget

Given an Image URL - it should show the URL in the image view
The entire screen should be occupied by this image - Do not break the aspect ratio - nor chop off any part of the image - it is ok to have some black area on the x axis or y axis to preserve the aspect ratio
The Imageview should adjust orientation as the device is moved to landscape & portrait mode.

Answer (score 0):

To just show an image, you may as well use the ImageView by setting layout parameters.

Suppose you want add zoom/pan functionality, then you will have to extend ImageView.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) should help you

Shash