# Zooming image in android

Tags: android

I want to add an image in my application which is like a road map image.
I want to add zooming features to this image as well as horizontal scrolling when the image is zoomed.

I have written some code but it allows only zooming and not scrolling.

Code:

```
public class Zoom extends View {
    private Drawable image;
    private int zoomControler=20;
    public Zoom(Context context)
    {
            super(context);
            image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boothmap);
            setFocusable(true);

    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
            image.draw(canvas);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)// zoom in
                    zoomControler+=10;
            if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) // zoom out
                    zoomControler-=10;
            if(zoomControler<10)
                    zoomControler=10;

            invalidate();
            return true;
    }
}
```

Can you help me solving this problem. Is my code proper so far or do you have any better code?

Comment: You need to pan or just scroll.

Comment: above code allows me to zoom but not scroll horizontally...so i want to scroll

Comment: Did u try my answer. If its still not working,try it.

Comment: I am trying it, but since I am new to android, I am not sure how to use it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what worked for me is : just add built in zoom controls to webview and then call its loadDataWithBaseURL method.

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src='file:///android_res/drawable/example.png' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this post :
[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images) 
You have to use webview.loadUrl("file://...") to load your image
and activate zoom option

Comment: I have this image in drawable folder and not as URL

Comment: Use  webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/example.png" />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);

Comment: I removed my code and instead just used loadUrl() method. Now it scrolls but doesnot zoom in or zoom out plus the image looks blurred now

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the image bounds instead of modofying the view bounds. Try modifying the view height and width. You should be able to scroll then. 
Will need to override `onMeasure()` method and set `setMeasuredDimension` as current height and width. Maintain the height and width as members.

EDIT:

```
class YourView extends View {
static Bitmap mOrignalBitmap = null; // check n load in constructor.

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) { 
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth,mHeight); 
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect src = new Rect(0,0, originalWidth, originalHeight);
        Rect dst = new Rect(viewLeft, viewTop, viewRight, viewBottom);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mOrignalBitmap , src, dst, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)// zoom in
                zoomControler+=10;
        if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) // zoom out
                zoomControler-=10;
        if(zoomControler<10)
                zoomControler=10;
        mWidth = //set view width with zoom
        mHeight = // set view height with zoom.
        requestLayout();

        return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Sorry I am fairly new to android so I dont know how to use this method. If you can guide me, it will be great

Comment: I have just added this in my code:


 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
         super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
         setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec,heightMeasureSpec);
        }

I dont know what to do now

Answer (score 0):

You'll get very bad results by trying to handle multi-touch with loadUrl. Try [this tutorial](http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/), It provides the best source code I found to do that. If you tweak a bit the code you can make it work on 2.1 as well.