# Android: Load Large Image from Assets Using Webview

Tags: android, image, web, webview

I need to load a large image (roughly 3500 x 3500 pixels) from assets using a webview.

I've done a lot of research here on Stackoverflow, and yet, none of the answers have worked for me. I figure it might be an issue with Android 4.0+ using assets.

My current code looks like:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/test.html");
```

test.html looks like:

```
<html>

  <table>

    <tr>

      <td>

        <img src="testimage.png" width="3500px" alt="TestAlt">

      </td>

    </tr>

  </table>

</html>
```

Both testimage.png and test.html are in the assets. Upon testing this on my physical Android device I get:

> Webpage not available
>   The webpage at file:///android_asset/test.html might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.

Logcat as requested:

```
I/webclipboard: clipservice:       android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@43ac41b0
V/webkit: BrowserFrame constructor:  this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {43ac3dc8}
D/WebView: loadUrlImpl: called
D/webcore: CORE loadUrl: called
D/webkit: Firewall not null
D/webkit: euler: isUrlBlocked = false
D/chromium: Unknown chromium error: -6
I/GATE: <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_ERROR</GATE-M>
V/webkit: reportError errorCode(-1) desc(There was a network error)
I/GATE: <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
I/Adreno200-EGLSUB: <ConfigWindowMatch:2136>: Format RGBA_8888.
D/WebView: onSizeChanged - w:480 h:0
D/WebView: onSizeChanged - w:480 h:446
```

Comment: can u post logcat here

Comment: @Stacks28 I've updated my question as requested.

Comment: hey hv u correctly given path right?check spelling again?

Comment: @Stacks28 Many, many times... I did some research just to make sure I was accessing the Android assets properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480245/2060140

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", "<img src='file:///android_res/drawable/example.png' />", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: This works! It's nice to be able to generate the HTML dynamically and get the local image included.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate method:
If you are able to use KitKat API level 19, and you are in control of the Webview so that there are no security issues to worry about...

Then:
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

With these settings, I was able to load information (initiated by the browser - Javascript)
to get file information from both the android_asset folders and the SD card.
Also to save information to the SDCard.

If anyone knows how to make this same thing work in V17 that would be great to know!?