# Unable to load local images in android webview

Tags: android

i am trying to load local images in android webview by using assets folder, but when i tries to open it, it is loading only HTML but not images

In my HTML Code i have added following line

```
<IMG SRC="file:///android_asset/images/a.jpg">
```

But it is not displaying image, can anybody please help?

Comment: try `src="images/a.png"` or `src="a.png"`

Comment: check this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928726/android-load-large-image-from-assets-using-webview

Comment: which method you are using to load the WebView?

Answer (score 0):

put your images into the Assets folders by creating separate images folder like `assets/images` and then in your html page provide path of your image as

```
  <IMG src="images/test.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

> first of which url loading in webview, is it local url or http (means requires internet). If ur loading local file system url pealse check the image path properly, it should work. if loading http url trying load a local images inside it sorry its not possible. Here its cross domain issue will restrict to that.