# implement zoom on scrollView android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am trying to create an application that employs the scrollView in Android. It so happens that scrollView does not support matrices. Therefore I can not do something like this:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix eventMatrix = new Matrix();
// possible touch states
final static int NONE = 0;
final static int DRAG = 1;
final static int ZOOM = 2;
int touchState = NONE;
```

Would anyone know if it is possible to attain the zooming as well as pinching functionality through other process? Appreciate the help.

Thanks.

[RE-EDIT]

The scrollView will serve as a container so that various UIs can be placed inside it. That way the scrollView can serve as one UI part.

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same requirement. Can you please share me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your specific requirements here are a couple possible approaches to this problem:

- You can create a view and adjust its layout parameters during the onScroll event.
- For plain zooming you might want to look at the  animation.  This should effectively give you a zoom effect. For a specific element in the scroll view.
- If you need to zoom the whole scrollView, you can surround it with a view container (eg LinearLayout) and perform the zoom on this view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are using the ScrollView for but you should take a look at this android developer article - [Making sense of multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html) to get pinch/zoom functionality.

Comment: The question is about zooming a scrollview, not handling multitouch events.

Comment: Actually, the question also asked "Would anyone know if it is possible to attain the zooming as well as pinching functionality through other process?". I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure "pinching" is a multitouch gesture ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to provide zoom capabilities to an image, then you're in luck! I wrote a fairly thorough class that extends ImageView to add pinch zoom and panning functionality, with boundary testing. Check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910). If that's not what you want, then you'll have to provide more information about exactly what you want to do. But, this code might be adaptable to your needs.

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the advice, however I am not working on images per say. I have re-edited my question so as to actually relay the purpose of my code. Thanks.