# zoom in and zoom out in android

Tags: android, zooming

Can any one help me about how to zoom in and zoom out images using a seek bar in android.
I followed the attached link for MapController but I want same implementation for images using seek bar for zoom in and zoom out.

The below links helps how to zoom in and out using seek bar for MapController.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/11/androidlocation-with-zoom-level-control.html

Thanks in advance

Shiv.

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a very general question so the best I can do is give you a general answer. You're basically just going to need have a different implementation of the `onProgessChanged` method which instead of zooming in and out on a map, zooms in and out on an image. For information on how to pragmatically zoom in an out of an image, checkout this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images).