# zoomable picture - android

Tags: java, android, zooming, image

How do I make a photo finger-zoomable on a android device? Is there a simple way, or is it complicated? But I dont want zoom buttons. I want it like a phonebrowser, when you take your fingers and drag them from each other on the phone, it will zoom in. How do I do?? I have searched everywhere. If there no way, can I just have two buttons, - and +. If I click one, the "imageview" change size?

How do I make a photo finger-zoomable on a android device? Is there a simple way, or is it complicated? But I dont want zoom buttons. I want it like a phonebrowser, when you take your fingers and drag them from each other on the phone, it will zoom in. How do I do?? I have searched everywhere. If there no way, can I just have two buttons, - and +. If I click one, the "imageview" change size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to load your image on a WebView and let it do all the work

```
webView.loadUrl("file://...")
```