# Looking for correct UI component

Tags: android, user-interface, components

On Android, I have .png images added as a resource in my /res/ folder.

Question: I want to display an image from the resource filling a screen, but allowing the user to pinch-to-zoom it. What UI component do I use? An ImageView? A WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in the assets folder, and point the WebView to it. The WebView will do everything for you, in terms of pinch to zoom functionality.