# Loading images in Android

Tags: android

I basically would like to load an image from a url to an activity or intent which allows me to zoom in and out and look at the image.

I first used the android.intent.action.View however this did not work on a 2.2 device but on my ICS device. I then decided why not create a WebView and just use that. However now the webView works nicely on my 2.2 device but not so great on my ICS device. on the ICS device I am never able to zoom out all the way. I am setting the builtInZoomControls(true);

When storing the image internally then displaying I get a blank screen however when I save the image to externalStorage it is fine. I am assuming this is due to permissions on the file. Some phones do not have external storage And I wanted a clean solution so I opted for the WebView.

I am essentially asking two questions. What is the best way to solve this problem, and if the web-view solution works how can i allow the image to zoom out on my ICS device.

Comment: what idiot down voted this and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your zooming problem see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7458910/476564). I've used it for zoomable images in my projects and it works perfectly. Just download the image to a byte array, then decode using BitmapFactory and you should be done.

Comment: thank you very much will check it out in the morning and respond correctly :)