# How to place buttons on a zoom&pan imageView

Tags: android, button, imageview, zooming

I would like a `ImageView` with buttons on it. The `ImageView` should have zoom/pan functionalities, while the buttons are zoomed as well, so they are always on the same position on the image.

ATM I use the `touchImageView` ([How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images))

Anyone has a (easy) solution to postion the `Button` ? Or should i calculate it like the Zoom/pan imageview works? Also tell me if i should use different way to zoom and pan on a `ImageView` to make this work..

Comment: Didn't found a solution. So i've created to whole view inside a webview..