# dynamically position views (similar to markers in Google Maps) on top of large scrollable + zoomable imageview

Tags: java, android

i have an imageview containing a bitmap that can be zoomed into and scrolled. i've used the setImageBitmap() method instead of setting the image on a canvas. the imageview acts as a map which the user can browse through. now, my application is supposed to allow the user to marker points of interest with push-pins as done in Google Maps on a point selected on the imageview by the user. i've gotten the ability to pick up which point on the original bitmap was selected using a modified implementation of the OnTouch() method to work so i know where exactly the marker has to be placed.
i want to set a marker to this location and pass a string into a database to store information about the location so that when the marker is tapped, this information is shown in a bubble/toast notification.

as of now, i can scroll the image, sense a longTouch event on the imageview, save point of tap, move to new activity to collect information to add in the database. i can't seem to find a way to set up my markers on the original imageview.
also, i'm guessing i'd have to use an ArrayList implementation here to get markers with individual IDs that could be correlated to the ID in the database fields but i don't understand how to implement that.

i looked around the Internet for a solution or an idea and i've tried many things before posting here but nothing seems to work.
using a canvas' draw functions wouldn't allow for onTap functions to show info notifications. the drawn bitmaps also lose scale and quality while zooming. i tried making a custom class extending RelativeLayout to act an an invisible layer on my imageview but i don't know how to place markers in exact locations and also make the custom RelativeLayout easier. i tried placing a false transparent canvas of the same dimensions as my bitmap to get scaling to work and allow me to place markers at absolute locations but it didn't work. plus, using onTouch events on the custom RelativeLayout class meant i couldn't use the onTouch events on the lower imageview class.

i can't seem to come up with any solutions that can help me implement the mechanism as i want to, so i'm open to any sorta idea that can be thrown at me. i'd appreciate some help.

Comment: Just a suggestion regarding how to pose/format your question in order to have the maximum chance of a response: less is often better (boil your question down to the bare minimum). Also, example code is always good (again, the less code the better).

Comment: i considered posting the code but my class already exceeds 300 lines so i thought it would be overkill.
my imageview code is basically a modification of Mike Ortiz's base code at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images to detect longTouch events and location of pixel on bitmap where the longTouch was performed.