# How to zoom in/out multiple images in Android?

Tags: android, zooming

I can zoom in and out with one image, but I have no idea how to zoom with multiple images.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images maybe helpful and make a search in here u will get lot of results