# Who has powerful ImageView like the one in Android Gallery App?

Tags: android, imageview, gallery, scale

The ImageView in Gallery in Android is great: it support scale smoothly and deal with OOM well. Now My project want to have such ImageView. Is anyone has such ImageView or know something hint about it? Thanks advanced~~

Comment: Check this out:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the Gallery uses OpenGL surfaces or some fancy stuff like that, not regular ImageViews.