# Zoom in Zoom out effect Using seek bar in android

Tags: android

I want to create Zoom in-out effect by using seek-bar & i also want this effect using touch as well...touch zoom in-out function is working fine but how can i implement this effect using seek bar...thanks in advance... Here my code is...

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnTouchListener {
private static final String TAG = "Touch";
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1f, MAX_ZOOM = 1f;
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.textImage);
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
    float scale;
    dumpEvent(event);
    // Handle touch events here...

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // first finger down only
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG"); // write to LogCat
        mode = DRAG;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // first finger lifted

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: // second finger lifted

        mode = NONE;
        Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: // first and second finger down

        oldDist = spacing(event);
        Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 5f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        if (mode == DRAG) {
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                    - start.y); // create the transformation in the matrix
                                // of points
        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            // pinch zooming
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 5f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                scale = newDist / oldDist; // setting the scaling of the
                                            // matrix...if scale > 1 means
                                            // zoom in...if scale < 1 means
                                            // zoom out
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    view.setImageMatrix(matrix); // display the transformation on screen

    return true; // indicate event was handled

}

private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}

private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);

    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }

    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }

    sb.append("]");
    Log.d("Touch Events ---------", sb.toString());
}
```

}

Comment: check this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106202/android-program-for-zoom-in-and-out-with-help-of-seekbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check my code. It will help you.
    Matrix matrix;

```
Matrix matrix;       
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int dis, boolean arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            view.setImageMatrix(matrix); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanx for your support @Samir ...but how can i create zoom in out effect on Image-View using this seek-bar..

Comment: I have added code only give you event on changes value of seekbar. To set zoom in or zoom out effect, you need to set imageMetrix at onProgressChanged() of my code. Check out my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Hellow i have a good code that will help you to zoom in and Zoom out By using the seekbar

you can need to add this on seekbar After initializing seekbar

```
  simpleSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                                      boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "progress:" + progress);
            if (camera.getParameters().isZoomSupported()) {
                Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                int maxZoom = params.getMaxZoom();
                int zoom = params.getZoom();
                simpleSeekBar.setMax(maxZoom);
                //zoom in
                if (zoom < maxZoom)
                    zoom++;
                //zoom out
                if (zoom > 0)
                    zoom--;
                params.setZoom(progress);
                camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "onStartTrackingTouch");
        }

    });
```

I Hope it will help you Enjoy