# Pinch Zoom in and Zoom Out

Tags: android, pinchzoom

i am using visit [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910) and got a project from visit https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView  .

But when i am doing run it . i got a image and did not get any Pinch zoom .

Do i need to change in this code:-

```
  TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(this);
  // ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap snoop = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snoopy);
    img.setImageBitmap(snoop);
    img.setMaxZoom(4f);
    setContentView(img);
```

please expert check it . Thank you for your kindly help.

Can any one help me By this project :- 
visit http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/04/pinching-zoom-in-android-image-view-or.html 
i used in my project . but i am not understanding how can i use this class.
i created my class which display image in imageview. and now i want to do pinchzoom

please check it expert . thank you

Comment: You can see easier and updated One here on the same site http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/04/update-pinch-to-zoom-example-and.html