# PInchZoom in android

Tags: android, pinchzoom

visit [Pinch Zoom in and Zoom Out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089031/pinch-zoom-in-and-zoom-out) this is my post but i didn't get answer still waiting.

Now i'm using this URL https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView project for `pinch zoom` . and i have run this project and got a picture . but i'm not `pichzoom` to this picture .

do i need to special key of keybord for `pinch zoom` . because i know about iphone where we need  ***(ALT + press mouse click )*** and got two finger print notation for zoom in and zoom out .

please help me that i'm using correct project . if yes, how can i `pinch zoom`

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Galleryview touch test Activity from this demo....

https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom/tree/master/ImageViewTouchTest/src/it/sephiroth/android/library/imagezoom/test this is the demo and in this demo there is GalleryTouchTestActivity
.java

also look at this link... [Android Image View Pinch Zooming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630373/android-image-view-pinch-zooming)

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply, may i use imageview with this demo. i was use this demo yesderday, and got zoom image by mouse clicked . but  we need a Pinchzoom "http://blog.csdn.net/sheofir/article/details/6448674"  here "point C " show pinch zoom .

Comment: Thank you ,i have run it and again got a picture . but how can i pinch zoom . do i need any other special key for check it demo pinch zoom

Comment: It is really good. but it give me zoom by mouse click . but i need pinchzoom . please tell me . how were you check it for pinchzoom . i used it :- first clicked on load image button and got image . and how can i use two finger zoom . please give me your kindly response

Comment: i have done checking this . but now when i clicked on button , i got a image. but now please tell me that how can i pinch zoom it . i am using eclipse android 4.1 emulator. thank you

Comment: please install it in device...it works perfectly...in emulator you can not do pinchzoom...

Comment: Thank you . you are looking nice person. currently i am creating a comic reader . i have created it . but i am unable to pinch zoom . my images are displaying from sd card one by one with previous and next . but here , i have not good mind so i use my imageview with this library . may you help me . I appreciate very much . if you want . please give me your email address i will send you my project . please help me. i have wasted my 1 month

Comment: please go to your directory and find your project and right click and create .rar file and send it...

Comment: I am sorry , i have not complete reputation for accepting answer . i promiss when i have completed . i will accept first your answer thank

Comment: Thank you ,I will wait . i have just checked it on my android phone . but not get till good response .i promiss you if my project will be run good , i will also help you when you need . i have corvered with this problem and my job may be left .  thank you

Comment: hello..can you send me you whole project because i have to reconfigure the files.....so, send me whole project...

Comment: i have again check it with GalleryTouchTestActivity and it is perfect working but is it possible in imageview . because i have tested both in android both and gallerytouchtestactivity working. i have just sent mail.

Comment: Thank you , i have created it with your help. is this library free . https://github.com/kilaka/ImageViewZoom

Comment: Yes , i have just solved it . Now i am designing . this is directory name . so make a folder in sdcard named comic