# How to properly set fixTransX & fixTransY of TouchImageView to implement doubleTap to ZoomOut?

Tags: android, zooming, android-imageview, android-gesture

I am using `TouchImageView` from [here](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java).

I am trying to implement `ZoomOut` for double tap. I have done it partially. But, I am facing some issues when zoomed out. If I zoom the Image & if I give a double tap, then image is not getting rendered properly.

Here is my modified version

TouchImageView.java

```
package com.bharath.downloadissuedemo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;


    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public TouchImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureListener(this));
    }

    public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new GestureListener(this));
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        last.set(curr);
                        start.set(last);
                        mode = DRAG;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {

                            float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                            float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                            float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                            float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                            fixTrans();
                            last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                        }
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        mode = NONE;

                        int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                        int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                        if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                            performClick();
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event); // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) 
    {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            System.out.println("Orig Scale = "+origScale);
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            System.out.println("Sace Scale = "+saveScale);

            System.out.println("m Scale Factor = "+mScaleFactor);
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

        System.out.println("Translation X ="+fixTransX);
        System.out.println("Translation Y ="+fixTransY);
        ((ViewPagerInterface)getContext()).enable();
        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        {           
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        }
        else if (saveScale!=1.0) 
        {
            ((ViewPagerInterface)getContext()).disable();
        } 
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        //
        // Rescales image on rotation
        //
        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            //Fit to screen.
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();            
            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);
            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;
            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }    

    private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        public TouchImageView touchImageView=null;

        public GestureListener(TouchImageView tmv) {

            touchImageView=tmv;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }
        // event when double tap occurs
        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
        {           
            if (saveScale>1.0f) {
                Drawable d = getDrawable();
                Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap();
                System.out.println("bmp Width = "+bmp.getWidth());
                System.out.println("bmp Height = "+bmp.getHeight());
                System.out.println("Original Width = "+origWidth);
                System.out.println("Original Height = "+origHeight);
                System.out.println("View Width "+viewWidth);
                System.out.println("View height"+viewHeight);
                float scaleX= viewWidth/(origWidth*saveScale);
                float scaleY =viewHeight/(origHeight*saveScale);
                float finalScale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);

                matrix.postScale(finalScale, finalScale, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
                saveScale=1.0f;

//              
//              float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (finalScale * (float) bmp.getHeight());
//              float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (finalScale * (float) bmp);
//              redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
//              redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;
//              matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

                 matrix.getValues(m);
                 float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                 float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

                 float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * finalScale);
                 float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * finalScale);
//
                 System.out.println("Translation X ="+transX);
                 System.out.println("Translation Y ="+transY);

                 System.out.println("Fix X ="+fixTransX);
                 System.out.println("Fix Y ="+fixTransY);
                 ((ViewPagerInterface)getContext()).enable();
                 matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
            }

//          fixTrans();


//          System.out.println("Intrinsic Width "+bmp.getWidth());
//          System.out.println("Intrinsic Height "+bmp.getHeight());
//          RectF drawableRect = new RectF(0, 0,bmp.getWidth(),bmp.getHeight());
//          RectF viewRect = new RectF(0, 0,getWidth(), getHeight());
//          m.setRectToRect(drawableRect, viewRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
//          setScale(,);
//          setScaleX(getWidth()/bmp.getWidth());
//          setScaleY( getHeight()/bmp.getHeight());

//setScaleX(scaleX)//           saveScale=1.0f;
//          setImageMatrix(m);

//          invalidate();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

//          System.out.println("SIngle Tap Occurred");
//          touchImageView.saveScale=1.0f;
//          touchImageView.invalidate();
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, please see the method

```
 public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
```

What was the mistake I made in the above method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### UPDATE

I've updated TouchImageView to include animated double tap zoom as well as fling. You can check it out on [github.](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView)

---

The basic approach is to save the original matrix when it is calculated in onMeasure. We cannot simply set `matrix = originalMatrix` as this is just setting two pointers to point to the same object. We need to make a deep copy which is done with: `matrix = new Matrix(originalMatrix);` We also need to reset `saveScale` to `1f` and call `invalidate()`.

```
public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;
Matrix originalMatrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 3f;
float[] m;


int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;


ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

Context context;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}

private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());
    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            invalidate();
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });
}

public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}

private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

        fixTrans();
        return true;
    }
}

private class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    // event when double tap occurs
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) 
    {      
        matrix = new Matrix(originalMatrix);
        saveScale = 1f;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

        // Center the image
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);
        originalMatrix = new Matrix(matrix);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
    }
    fixTrans();
}
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I cannot still implement doubleTap to zoomIn to maximum(keeping tap position in center). Please Help

Comment: @PankajVatsa I wanted to implement doubleTap to zoom in to maximum too.. did you manage to find a solution?