# How to sync TouchImageView to zoom and scroll more than 1 control at a time

Tags: android, scroll, imageview

I'm trying to modify https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView so I can have n TouchImageViews, and when zooming in one control, the other get zoomed automatically with it.

I would like to replicate the operation (eg: Zooming, Scrolling, etc) in any of the View automatically for all other "registered" view. But I'm failing in understand the code

Related: [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910)

Comment: The point is the setImageMatrix(matrix) method, you can apply it to all the ImageViews.

Comment: @eklam  have u successfully scroll TouchImageView  i am failed to scroll zoom images can u pls help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480190/how-to-scroll-horizontally-and-vertically-imageview-in-touchimageview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

In the method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
 . . . 
 }
```

adding some observer pattern you could add a callback to the referenced "controls", next you coud resize it seeing the method

```
matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2, viewHeight / 2);
```

this was my first approach

Comment: have u successfully scroll TouchImageView  i am failed to scroll zoom images can u pls help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480190/how-to-scroll-horizontally-and-vertically-imageview-in-touchimageview-in-android