# how do i add zoom in zoom out programmatically?

Tags: android

This is my code below which crete layout programically. How do i set zoom in and zoom out programicallly when click on image? I want my program to react when user click on image is enlarge full screen and when click again is go resume original size what do i do?

```
    final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(this);  
     dbConnector.open();
     Cursor cursor =  
    dbConnector.getStageRequirements(Long.valueOf(currentStageID).longValue());
     reqdata = new MyData1[cursor.getCount()];
     int j = cursor.getCount();
     cursor.moveToFirst();
     i = 0;
     while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) 
     {
         reqdata[i] = new MyData1(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(0));
         cursor.moveToNext();
         i++;
     }
     dbConnector.close();
     cursor.close();

     ScrollView scroll = new ScrollView(MainActivity1.this);
     scroll.setLayoutParams(new  
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));      

     btnLO = new LinearLayout(MainActivity1.this);  
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO = new  
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     // button margins
     paramsLO.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);


     LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLO2 = new  
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     // button margins
     paramsLO2.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
     // button height/width *pixels*

     btnLO.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
     btnLO.setBackgroundColor(5); // not working correctly

     //buttons
     for (i =0;i <reqdata.length;i++)
         {
             LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(this);
             li.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
             final Button b1 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);
             final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity1.this);
             int width = 60;
             int height = 150;
             LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new  
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
             parms.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(parms);

             li.addView(b1, paramsLO);        
             li.addView(imageView);
             btnLO.addView(li);

             b1.setText(reqdata[i].getSpinnerText());

             b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                    {
                        public void onClick(View v) 
                        {               


                             imageView1 = imageView;
                             Intent pictureActionIntent = new  
  Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 

  pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new  
  File(SDCARD_ROOT_PATH + SAVE_PATH_IN_SDCARD,IMAGE_CAPTURE_NAME)));  

 startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent,CAMERA_PICTURE);
                             b1.setClickable(false);


                          } 

                    });    

         }

     final Button b2 = new Button(MainActivity1.this);

     b2.setText("Submit");
     b2.setWidth(150);
     b2.setHeight(50);
     b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
     {
         public void onClick(View v) 
         {                           

             long visitID = dbConnector.saveVisit();

             for (i =0;i <reqdata.length;i++)
             {
                 dbConnector.saveVisitDetail(listByte.get(i),visitID,Long.valueOf(reqdata[i].getValue()).longValue());
             }     
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sucessful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity1.this, Main.class);     
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
         }
     }); 
     btnLO.addView(b2, paramsLO2);
     btnLO.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER| Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
     scroll.addView(btnLO);

     this.addContentView(scroll, new LayoutParams());

}
```

Comment: i want when i click image which i capture is enlarge and when click again resume to original size

Answer (score 0):

Like [Lalit Poptani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726863/lalit-poptani) said in another answer,

> There is a nice running answer for this question on StackOverflow.
>   Please have a look at this, [PinchZoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)