# Use of Zoom in ImageView inside ScrollView

Tags: android, imageview, zooming, scrollview

I'm trying to use `zoom` in an `ImageView`. I've searched and tried so many codes but the problem is that I have `ImageView` inside an `ScrollView` because I have some other objects.

[This](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) is the last code if tried.

And here is **xml code:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".ConsumoActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLogoFactor_consumo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/imageViewLogoFactor_consumo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_factorenergia" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewConsumo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutConsumo2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/textViewVerConsumo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="@string/etiqueta_ver_consumo"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"
                android:textColor="#79b7e3" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDireccionConsumo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:weightSum="1.0">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewlabelDireccionConsumo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:text="@string/etiqueta_direccion"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDireccionConsumo"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textSize" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <com.example.factorenergia.CustomImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewConsumo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
                android:scaleType="matrix" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutImagenInferior_consumo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewImagenInferior_consumo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/la_electrica_de_las_empresas" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Image is ok but `scroll` is not working. Is there any way for solving that having `ImageView` inside `ScrollView` with some other objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used an easy solution:

Let my layout as it was and when `ImageView` is clicked, go to a new one which only has the `Image`, using Mike Ortiz code at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the overriden ImageView is handling all touch events. It should take only two-finger events and pass the rest of them back to the parent. You should return false from onTouchEvent, when the event is not for your ImageView.

The second option is to handle events in dispatchTouchEvent method of the ScrollView. You can handle one-finger events in the ScrollView and pass the rest of events to children. This is not recomended, because it may break a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Zielony clarified things for me, as I was struggling with a similar issue. I had a zoomable imageview inside scrollView, and both these views were conflicting. So I created a custom scrollView that intercepts touch events only if one finger is touching the screen. So, you will be able to interact with the imageview zooming feature with two fingers, and scroll our custom scrollView with one finger.

```
class CustomScrollView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : ScrollView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
       return if (ev.pointerCount < 2) {
           super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)
       } else {
           false
       }
    }
}
```