# How to add zoom feature without loosing the x and y layout coordinates

Tags: java, android, imageview, zooming, coordinates

I have an image which shows different toasts when touched in different sections. Here is the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
{
    String xcoordinate, ycoordinate;
    Integer xint, yint;
    Double xdoub, ydoub;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.lyt);
        touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
            {
                xcoordinate = String.valueOf(event.getX());
                ycoordinate = String.valueOf(event.getY());

                xdoub = Double.valueOf(xcoordinate);
                ydoub = Double.valueOf(ycoordinate);

                xint =  xdoub.intValue();
                yint =  ydoub.intValue();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Touch coordinates : " +
                String.valueOf(event.getX()) + "x and " + String.valueOf(event.getY()) + "y", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                LaunchPopup();    
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public void LaunchPopup()
    {
        if(xint > 243 && xint < 307 && yint > 315 && yint < 410)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Center", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(xint > 330 && xint < 394 && yint > 24 && yint < 122)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Manual 68 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(xint > 330 && xint < 394 && yint > 154 && yint < 250)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Manual 79 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(xint > 330 && xint < 394 && yint > 314 && yint < 410)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Manual 17 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(xint > 330 && xint < 394 && yint > 458 && yint < 554)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Manual 45 Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        else if(xint > 330 && xint < 394 && yint > 602 && yint < 700)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Group Task Section", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now its working fine when the image is fit to screen. But what I want is to add zoom feature to the image without loosing the main function of particular toast on particular sections of the image. Is there any way to do this.? I mean is there anything by which I can represent the ratio of the zoom with the change in x and y coordinates.? So that the image should still do the same action when touched in that particular section even after zoom.?

Comment: visit https://github.com/laurencedawson/ZoomableImageView

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE
I've just given TouchImageView a new update. It now includes Double Tap Zoom and Fling in addition to Panning and Pinch Zoom. The code below is very dated. You can check out the [github project to get the latest code](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

USAGE
Place TouchImageView.java in your project. It can then be used the same as ImageView. Example:

```
TouchImageView img = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

If you are using TouchImageView in xml, then you must provide the full package name, because it is a custom view. Example:

```
<com.example.touch.TouchImageView
    android:id="@+id/img”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Note: I've removed my prior answer, which included some very old code and now link straight to the most updated code on [github](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images

Comment: i gave a +1 vote for yours answer for the work as you really updated a great piece of work at github

Comment: @404 what about responses on touch of different x and y coordinates in the same image.? Will it work.?

Answer (score 1):

```
ZoomableImageView img = (ZoomableImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
```

If you are using ZoomableImageView in xml, then you must provide the full package name, because it is a custom view. Example:

```
<com.example.touch.ZoomableImageView
    android:id="@+id/img”
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

beside this you can go with have a look on project
https://github.com/laurencedawson/ZoomableImageView

Comment: what about responses on touch of different x and y coordinates in the same image.? Will it work.?

Comment: hope it will work.please have a look at source. i will also investigate and will inform you. please give me few minutes.

Comment: Okay.. Thanx.. Actually I am not so aware of android, so any help would be so so great. I will check the source.