# Save original image (.png) even when zoomed

Tags: android, image, imageview, zooming

I have an apps that let the user to add text/image to the main image, and the main image can be zoomed.

My current problem is the produced PNG file is also zoomed if the main image is in zoomed position. My code is saving whatever is displayed to the user, instead of keeping the original image. I currently use `getDrawingCache()` method.

How to let the user zoom in/zoom out my main image but saving the original image instead of the zoomed image?

Thanks

Comment: you probably are using some custom View for zooming,  right?

Comment: @pskink yes. im using custom view

Comment: so how do you expect anyone could answer your question without knowing what view you are using and how?

Comment: @pskink i zoom the image using this library : https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

I use some custom view to the other view, but not in my main image.

Comment: does PhotoView add text/image to the main image?

Comment: @pskink no, i code it manually and using some custom views i.e. for textview. I think the main problem is in the zoom-able main image view. (which i only using that library)

Comment: use custom Drawable instead of custom View,  implement draw method and use that Drawable in PhotoView

Comment: @pskink Do you have any code/tutorial how to do that regarding of my problem? Thanks

Comment: no i don't have, just extend BitmapDrawable for example and override its draw method

Comment: @pskink what should i override? I still dont get your idea

Comment: override its draw method

Comment: @pskink I mean what should i put in the ondraw method to achieve my goal?

Comment: canvas.drawText, canvas.drawBitmap

Comment: and not ondraw but draw, you should override draw method