# how to make android layout which is scrollable and zoomable?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make a layout like shown in images below. it's like googlemap and you can zoom in/out with multi finger touch, and also scrolling in four way. is there any library supporting this layout?

zoomed out image:
[http://i57.tinypic.com/2hoz6rl.png][1]

zoomed in and scrolled:
[http://i58.tinypic.com/zxnqqb.png][2]
.....
third pic in the comments

Comment: another pic:
more zoomed in and scrolled to corner:
[http://i62.tinypic.com/107qoom.png][3]

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView element in your xml

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/someId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

 <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalSomeId"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

`enter code here`

</HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TouchImageView.

Refers this link.

[How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images/7458910#7458910)

From here you can download TouchImageView class or Library.

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView
https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

If its works for you then give me a Check mark for correct answer.