# Zoom the particular portion of image

Tags: android, imageview

I would like to zoom the image to particular portion(user input coordinates) of the image.

When I click on a button I would like to zoom the image to particular coordinates of the image.

Can anyone help me out to find the zoom function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get zoom functionality for images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537238/how-can-i-get-zoom-functionality-for-images)

Comment: Best to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use view.setPivot before view.setScale

If you arent targeting API 11+ theres a calculation that took me 4 attempts along of 3 years to make it work, if you need it I can search after.